# MeCabでのユーザー辞書が生成できない。

Tags: windows, mecab

MeCabでユーザー辞書の追加を行っていますがうまくいかず、困っています。
いくつかのサイトを参考にし下記を実行してdoneまで表示されるのですが
dicファイルが生成されません。
なにか修正点などあればご教示ください。

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MeCab\bin>mecab-dict-index -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MeCab\dic\ipadic" -u ComeJisyoV3.dic -f utf-8 -t utf-8 ComeJisyoV3.csv
reading ComeJisyoV3.csv ... 41592
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|

done!
```

Comment: MeCabに詳しくなく申し訳ないのですが、出力ディレクトリを```C:\Program Files (x86)\```以外にしても作成されないでしょうか？ 管理者権限で実行していないことが原因で、ファイル作成に失敗している可能性があります。

Comment: D:\として実行したところ、生成されました。
コマンドラインで扱うのが初めてで初歩的なところに引っかかっていたようです。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

恐らく管理者権限が関係していると思われたので、出力先ディレクトリの指定を`C:\Program Files (x86)`以外の場所、今回は`D:\`を指定して実行したところファイルが生成されました。

---

この回答は [@Wataru Harakita さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/25428/mecab%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a6%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b6%e3%83%bc%e8%be%9e%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8c%e7%94%9f%e6%88%90%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment24231_25428) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。